# maven generate-sources -identify generated source paths from a plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm trying to write a maven plugin that required to check the generated-sources directories. Can I have the configuration of other plugins and poms which would be interpreted as generated paths

Comment: Can you give more details what you like to achieve and what you mean by `...check the generated-sources directories` ?...

Comment: I'm trying to get all directories where the current maven project is trying to generate the source files after generate-sources phase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

outputDirectory property should be present in the plugin configuration if one want to designate a different directory to look for generated sources otherwise would be default code gen directory of maven.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.abc.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>myprocessor</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/generated</outputDirectory>
      </configuration> 
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies/>
</plugin>
```